# Use external alias with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to simultaneously use two versions of the same control on a ASP.NET MVC3 application.

I've used the external assembly alias feature to define both in the C# code, but I can't find how to write the correct code to use them on an ASP.NET element (master, view or control).

The most similar question I've found, is this: [External alias in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815492/external-alias-in-xaml), but I can't apply the solution on my code.  It would be very hard to rewrite all needed classes. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: I've no code to post, it adds nothing new. It's a general problem: use "external alias xxxx" sentence on an ASP.NET element.